# Django 3: Unsure why I'm getting CSRF error

Tags: python, django, debugging, jinja2, csrf

I'm writing a Django app and my registration page raises a 403 error:

> Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> Reason given for failure:
>
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Here's the view:

```
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, "register.html", {'form' : form})
```

Here's the form in the relevant template:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="button">Register</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Some relevant facts:

(1) No other pages on my site throw this error even though many require CSRF tokens.

(2) The code I use to insert the CSRF token is the same in this template as in others (unless my triple-checking has failed me).

(3) [probably relevant?] This is the only form I'm importing directly into views.py without modifying first in forms.py. So, two lines of views.py are:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
[...]
from foo.forms import FooForm, FooBarForm, UploadFooForm
```

Any and all help appreciated. I've tried most of what I think are the obvious debugging steps (removing the {% csrf_token %} line, reading the debug output and ensuring [I think] that those issues don't apply to me, etc.).

EDIT: I'm working in Django 3. I've seen another question and received a response about the @csrf_exempt decorator, but I believe that the relevant decorator is no longer available in Django 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer which i am providing is not usable for a long run but for negleting this error we can use the django's inbuilt decorators methods , just import the csrf_exempt and add the decorator above the function where its showing the error.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, "register.html", {'form' : form})
```

Hope it helps and u learnt something new , happy coding...

Comment: Thanks! I checked for it but had somehow missed it (autocomplete error or simple user error).

Answer (score -2):

try removing the migration file and db file, then makemigrations and migrate again.